# Convert all columns in a Dataframe to a single secondary index in a MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe called Pop that looks like the following (Sorry, this doesn't format very well, but it's a single Index DataFrame (State is the index) with columns for each year. I only put a small sample of the data):

```
           2007    2008    2009
State                               
Alabama 4637904 4677464 4708708
```

Is there a way to easily convert this to a MultiIndex DataFrame where the Year becomes a secondary index. The only item is a new field 'Population' that takes the data from the original dataFrame. It would ideally look something like:

```
                Population
State     Year

Alabama   2007     4637904

Alabama   2008     4677464

Alabama   2009     4708708
```

etc...

I've been looking for some kind of code since this seems like something that could be handled in Python. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to convert columns into rows :

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
     state      2007      2008      2009
0  Alabama   4637904   4677464   4708708
1    Maine   1234567   1432765   1432567
2  Florida  19432765  19123456  19765654

In [13]: out = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['state'], var_name=['year'], value_name='population')

In [14]: out
Out[14]: 
     state  year  population
0  Alabama  2007     4637904
1    Maine  2007     1234567
2  Florida  2007    19432765
3  Alabama  2008     4677464
4    Maine  2008     1432765
5  Florida  2008    19123456
6  Alabama  2009     4708708
7    Maine  2009     1432567
8  Florida  2009    19765654
```

And finally setting the index :

```
In [15]: out.set_index(['state', 'year'])
Out[15]: 
              population
state   year            
Alabama 2007     4637904
Maine   2007     1234567
Florida 2007    19432765
Alabama 2008     4677464
Maine   2008     1432765
Florida 2008    19123456
Alabama 2009     4708708
Maine   2009     1432567
Florida 2009    19765654
```

PS : I used random values for the states population